# keep recording audio even if camera takes photo

Tags: audio, camera, microphone, audio-recording

How can I take a photo without having to restart recording audio? I have a lecturer who's handwriting on the board must be deciphered after class, but I don't want to bring two devices to class, one for audio and one for photos. The stock software basically crashes the record app if the camera is started. I think my old flip-phone might have better multitasking...

Device in particular is a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, but I am curious about android devices in general.

Answer (score 2):

On my Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a Android 4.1.2, I use [Camera Zoom FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom&hl=en) (non-free): it can take pictures without stopping recordings done by Android's native voice recorder (unlike the native camera application).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a third party application to voice record? If you disable the shutter sound and use something like Smart Voice Record, I'm able to successfully voice record and take pictures without a problem.

Comment: How do you disable shutter sound? Everything I am using is stock.

Comment: Click the settings gear icon in the camera, then youll get a pop up and tap on another gear icon scroll down and turn shutter sound off. Also, use Smart Voice Record.

Comment: There is no option for shutter sound.

Comment: There has to be. I also have a Note 3.

Comment: I think perhaps it has been removed depending on cellphone service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, you can still probably just use Smart Voice Recorder anyways even with the Shutter on just turn the volume all the way down to silent.

Comment: That doesn't work on my phone, although it may on other non-verizon phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skyro Voice Recorder](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.triveous.recorder) which does both voice recording and has ability to attach pictures to recordings. Now you can create nice lectures with audio and images synced.

It automatically attaches pictures taken during the recording to your audio, you can also add photos from gallery/dropbox/drive etc. Amazing app all these features are completely free. The new version of the app does it really well, automatically create a slideshow at the end of the recording with images taken during the recording.